# How to use environment variable in project.pbxproj file?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a react native application built and distributed through microsoft appcenter. for the iOS side, I have a release variant which is the live production variant. and i have a staging variant. the git flow im trying to achieve is something like this:

1. create feature branch from either master or staging (for the sake of
   this argument) -->
2. push OTA update to staging variant -->
3. merge staging variant into master (this is the key part)

***I want to be able to merge staging into master without having to manually set the `defaultConfigurationName` each time i pull staging into master, or push the master-branched-feature-branch to staging. I want a dynamic value: master's value to always be 'release' and staging to always be 'staging'.***

Problem:
When merging staging branch into master branch (production), the `defaultConfigurationName` in project.pbxproj changes the variant that will be built by microsoft appcenter from the release variant (production) to the staging variant

[image]

lets say i have an env variable called "ENVIRONMENT", with values of 'release' and 'staging', corresponding to 'master' and 'staging branches. i want to automate management of the ios build configuration when merging staging into master, and not have to manually reset `defaultConfigurationName` back to 'release' each time i merge staging into master. how can i set the env variable's value to the value of "defaultConfigurationName" in project.pbxproj file?

Note: i dont need help setting up environments or environment variables. i also dont want to create an additional target.

Comment: Could you clarify the way you define the environment variable before?

Comment: @itachi its defined in a script that runs pre-build during appcenter's build process. accessed like other env variables. but i dont know how to use an env variable natively, in the project.pbxproj file

Comment: Suggest duplicating the existing `Release` project configuration to your preferred release channel and define different **Preprocesor Macros** for them separately and use them in one code base with `#if #elif #end`.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue and found that you can update the info.plist file found in ios/app/app/info.plist to include your environment variables.

Eg

```
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(CAPACITOR_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
```

Comment: Does this work when running locally as well? I haven't figure that part out

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at [this](https://medium.com/swlh/setting-up-multiple-environments-on-react-native-for-ios-and-android-c43f3128754f) blog post, it shows how to set up multiple environments for android and iOS.

Comment: the question isnt about how to setup env variables. i already have them setup. the question is how to use the environment variables in the project.pbxproj file